# Elasticsearch 7 : Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters (mapper_parsing_exception)

Tags: elasticsearch

When trying to insert the following mapping in Elasticsearch 7

```
PUT my_index/items/_mapping
{
   "settings":{

   },
   "mappings":{
      "items":{
         "properties":{
            "products":{
               "properties":{
                  "classification":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "raw":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "original_text":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "store":false,
                     "fields":{
                        "raw":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            },
            "title":{
               "type":"text",
               "fields":{
                  "raw":{
                     "type":"keyword",
                     "ignore_above":256
                  }
               },
               "analyzer":"autocomplete"
            },
            "image":{
               "properties":{
                  "type":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "fields":{
                        "raw":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "location":{
                     "type":"text",
                     "store":false,
                     "fields":{
                        "raw":{
                           "type":"keyword",
                           "ignore_above":256
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I get an error of the form:

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [
    {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: There are some other questions that have been asked that are very similar, but they are all related to specific uses or relate to versions of Elasticsearch before 7.0.0  The goal of this question / answer is to have a single, clean, generalizable answer for Elasticsearch 7 as this will likely be a common problem as people upgrade from previous versions to ES 7

Answer (score 27):

In Elasticsearch 7, mapping types have been deprecated, which is causing the breaking change at the source of this problem.

[Announcement](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/removal-of-types.html) by the Elasticsearch team of the deprecation, roadmap, and alternatives.

To fix this, simply remove all references to mapping types ("items" in this example):

```
PUT my_index/_mapping
{
   "settings":{

   },
   "mappings":{
      "properties":{
         "products":{
            "properties":{
               "classification":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "fields":{
                     "raw":{
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "original_text":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "store":false,
                  "fields":{
                     "raw":{
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "title":{
            "type":"text",
            "fields":{
               "raw":{
                  "type":"keyword",
                  "ignore_above":256
               }
            },
            "analyzer":"autocomplete"
         },
         "image":{
            "properties":{
               "type":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "fields":{
                     "raw":{
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "location":{
                  "type":"text",
                  "store":false,
                  "fields":{
                     "raw":{
                        "type":"keyword",
                        "ignore_above":256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Another temporary solution to smooth the transition to ES7 is to include `?include_type_name=true` in the URL.

Comment: Thanks. The answer might be in the documentation but it's nice to have a simple question + answer to refer to. The only enhancement I would suggest would be to mention that type == index now, as that is maybe not easy to wrap your head around when you're used to thinking of the index as a database and the type as a table in it!

Answer (score -2):

You have to upgrade your elasticsearch version only.. everything will be sort out..